# Repeated Consent Screen with Dropbox Core API

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I am building an Android App using the Dropbox Core API.Every time the app tries to retrieve the data from Dropbox, he is presented with the Consent Screen.I want this Consent Screen to appear only once during the login.
Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your app is programmed to call `startOAuth2Authentication` (or the like) every time it tries to retrieve the data from Dropbox. Instead, you should have your app call it once, and then save and re-use the access token that you get back. The [tutorial](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/android) for the Dropbox Android Core SDK says:

> You'll need this token again after your app closes, so it's important
>   to save it for future access (though it's not shown here). If you
>   don't, the user will have to re-authenticate every time they use your
>   app. A common way to implement storing keys is through Android's
>   [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) API.

Comment: I am using SharedPreferences.Infact,the SDK isn't asking me to login again and again,it's just the Consent Screen which appears evertytime.

Comment: Have you checked if you're calling startOAuth2Authentication repeatedly? And to clarify, when you say "consent screen", do you mean the page where Dropbox asks if you want to link the app to your Dropbox account, or something else?

Comment: Yes,Consent Screen is the one which requests the user to allow the access of Dropbox files and folders to the application.

Comment: I would add some logging to see when you're calling startOAuth2Authentication (or startAuthentication in older versions I believe), as that should be the only thing that triggers the authorization flow.